# IRedisClient GetTypedClient not found

Tags: servicestack.redis

I get error IRedisClient does not contain definition of GetTypedClient:

```
   private readonly IRedisClient _redisClient; 

    public CustomerRepository(IRedisClient redisClient)
    {
        _redisClient = redisClient;
    }

    public IList<Order> GetAll()
    {
        using(var typedClient = _redisClient.GetTypedClient<Customer>())
        {
            return typedClient.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Is it depreciated?

Answer (score 2):

The [API to get a Typed Redis client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/3e88830581f8985fd83734bd574c3c1246ba8cac/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L157) is `As<T>`, e.g:

```
using(var typedClient = _redisClient.As<Customer>())
{
    return typedClient.GetAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That method is now located in IRedisTypedClient. The documentation can be found here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisTypedClient